# JPA and Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I plan on using Google App Engine to communicate with an Android App. I am planning on using Objectify, which uses JPA annotations, and serialize them using the built in XML libraries. If I wanted to use the same object on both ends, what should I do about the annotations (such as @Id, etc)?

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Very interested to know what is the "correct" approach to this - Should the same object be used on both ends, or should the annotated Objectify object only be used within AppEngine itself, and an non-annotated object be used for communication with the Android App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from version 4 Objectify no longer uses JPA/JDO annotations.

Bad thing is that annotation only jar is not supplied in default Objectify distribution. You'd need to check out its sources and build "client-jar" nant target that you'd put into your Android application.